# Which spell did this character use in Fantastic Beasts: The Secrets of Dumbledore?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-secrets-of-dumbledore

Spoiler warning for the ending of *Fantastic Beasts: The Secrets of Dumbledore* (2022).

> At the end of the movie, you can see Grindelwald using a green spell against and towards Credence.

Which spell was cast?

Comment: Note: If you're going to spoiler the question then the tags shouldn't negate that.

Comment: Might have to wait for confirmation; https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Fantastic_Beasts:_The_Secrets_of_Dumbledore_-_The_Complete_Screenplay

Answer (score 5):

#### It most likely was Avada Kedavra.

After the spell in question was cast, Albus Dumbledore said

> he (Dumbledore) was aiming to protect Credence and Grindelwald was aiming to kill Credence.

In addition, there were several other people who were likely to attempt to stop Grindelwald from attacking the person, he was likely to use the fastest spell possible to ensure death - he wouldn’t have been trying for a slow torturous death, he would have wanted it done before anyone could stop him. Considering that he was aiming to kill, would have wanted it done quickly, and that his spell was indeed green like Avada Kedavra, it most likely was Avada Kedavra.

Comment: How do you think this spell was blocked then by using 2 spells casted from percival and albus, as AK would be unblockable (except for physical object). Would this be love? or Directly BOUNCED off the spell by using an other spell?

Comment: @Roel It was directly bounced off the other spells, which has been shown to stop Killing Curses before. *“More Killing Curses flew past Harry’s head from the two remaining Death Eaters’ wands; they were aiming for Hagrid. Harry responded with further Stunning Spells: red and green collided in mid-air in a shower of multi-coloured sparks and Harry thought wildly of fireworks, and the Muggles below who would have no idea what was happening –” - Chapter 4 (The Seven Potters) Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*